# CSV file usage in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have csv file contains URL and port no.i want to pass in all samplers.How to do that?

I have tried ${URL},${Port_no}.but,it is of no use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working, If you CSV holds for example:

```
www.google.com,80
```

Configure the CSV Data Set Config:

[image]

And add [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) with Server Name as `${URL}` and port as `${Port_no}`

Answer (score 0):

If there is only 2 values you would like to parameterize the easier option would be:

1. Pass the URL and the Port_no via [-J command-line arguments](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) like:

   ```
   jmeter -JURL=http://example.com -JPort_no=443
   ```
2. Add [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults) configuration element to your Test Plan and refer the properties using __P() function like:

   - `${__P(URL,)}`
   - `${__P(Port_no,)}`
3. In your [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers leave the relevant fields blank - they will be populated from the HTTP Request Defaults.